# Oracle SQL CORR function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small project for school but I am struggling to get past one part of it. I have two columns so my table would look like the below example. My objective is to try to use some sort of function within Oracle SQL Developer to determine if there is a correlation between the two data sets. I was considering using the CORR function but I don't think that would work as there are too many unique runtimes. Any thoughts are appreciated.

| Runtime | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | 9.5 |
| 238 | 9.9 |
| 228 | 9.1 |
| 225 | 8.5 |
| 221 | 8.3 |

Comment: I believe you have a maths/statistics problem (lack of understanding), not a programming question. What do you think "a correlation between the two data sets" means? "Correlation" is defined for any two non-constant data sets; it "exists", and it can be calculated, for any two such data sets. Do you want to know if their correlation coefficient is greater than .9, for example? That's trivial to do. But then, you talk about "too many unique runtimes". What's that got to do with anything? That has nothing to do with "correlation".

Answer (score 1):

Creating a small table for testing, using your values:

```
create table t (runtime, rating) as
  select 321, 9.5 from dual union all
  select 238, 9.9 from dual union all
  select 228, 9.1 from dual union all
  select 225, 8.5 from dual union all
  select 221, 8.3 from dual
;
```

The query and result look like this:

```
select round(corr(runtime, rating), 2) as correl from t;

    CORREL
----------
        .5
```

The correlation coefficient is 0.5. The two quantities are positively correlated, 0.5 is significant; but they are not perfectly (or even "almost perfectly") correlated: the correlation coefficient is not close to 1.

In any case, any further interpretation of the result (either on this small test or on your actual, real-life data) is in the field of statistics - it has nothing to do with programming.